# Do the sentences have the same meaning?

Tags: prepositions

1. We were served by a very impolite salesgirl at the supermarket.
2. We were served by a very impolite salesgirl from the supermarket.

I'd like to know whether the sentences have the same meaning.

I think that *at the supermarket* is an adverb phrase, and *from the supermarket* is an adjective phrase.

If the sentences are changed into active, is it correct to place the phrase (*at/from the supermarket*) behind the subject?

Comment: Please expand your question to tell us whether **you** think the sentences have the same meaning. Do you think _at the supermarket_ and _from the market_ have different meanings here?

Comment: Thanks, P.E. Dant.I think 'at the supermarket' is an adverb phrase and 'from the supermarket' is an adjective phrase.

Comment: Please use the `edit` button below your question to **expand the question to include your comment**. Also, tell us what you think the two phrases mean. That will make your question much better!

Comment: Now you it will be even better if you tell us what **you** think your two sentences mean. Tell us how **you** think the two phrases **from the supermarket** and **from the supermarket** are different.

Comment: I've told you how I think the two phrases are different. One is an adverb, and another is an adjective.

Comment: Please improve your question. Tell us what you think your two sentences **mean.** Do you think they have different **meanings?**

Comment: Both clauses are _already_ in the passive voice!

Answer (score 3):

Your two sentences contain two different *prepositional phrases* which, as you thought, function as an adverbial and adjectival phrase, respectively.

> 1. We were served by a very impolite salesgirl **at the supermarket**.
> 2. We were served by a very impolite salesgirl **from the supermarket**.

The adverbial phrase in the first sentence tells us that the *serving* took place *at the supermarket.* We know that the speakers were served at the supermarket, and by a rude salesgirl.

The adjectival phrase in the second sentence modifies *salesgirl* by telling us about her place of origin. The assumption is that *the supermarket* is where she works. The adjectival phrase doesn't tell us where the rude service was endured by the speakers, though. It may have been at the bus station, on a roller coaster, or at the supermarket.

Like an adverb, an adverbial prepositional phrase can be moved around in a sentence. If we express the main clause in the first sentence in the passive voice, we *can* place the adverbial prepositional phrase before the subject:

> 1. **At the supermarket,** a very impolite salesgirl served us.

If we express the main clause in the second sentence in the passive voice, we *cannot* change the position of the adjectival prepositional phrase relative to the noun it modifies. Unlike adjectives, which usually precede the nouns they modify, an adjectival prepositional phrase follows the noun it modifies. Here, the prepositional phrase modifies *salesgirl* and must immediately follow it:

> 2. A very impolite salesgirl **from the supermarket** served us.

Comment: Thanks, P.E. Dant. I'm sorry for my tying error. Please read 'active' instead of 'passive'. I'll edit it.